# Error message - Invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Tags: c

A program to convert a document into an array of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int i,j;
    char *a[1000],c,*z; 
    z=a;
    for(i=0;(c=getchar())!=EOF;i++)
        {    if(c==' '||c=='\n')
            {
                z+=1;
                i=0;
                continue;
            }
            *(*(z)+i)=c;
        }
}
```

I wanted to write a program to take input from the user and save the input as an array of words. But when I tried to run the code it showed the error earlier mentioned.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should have also gotten a warning for `z=a;`

Comment: It didn't show an error for z=a moreover isn't array name a pointer to the first element essentially won't the statement be assigning address of the element?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use int as return type for main(), as the default return type for main() is int.
Array name is itself a pointer so remove the pointer in array declaration:      `char *a[1000]` to `char a[1000]`.

Now just remove the pointer from z variable in line no.18 of your code:
`*(*(z)+i)=c;` to `*((z)+i)=c;`

Hope this helps to works out the code you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer arithmetic is way off, and `*a[1000]` is an array of 1000 pointers, you really need something more like

```
int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    char a[1000][100], c;
    i = 0, j = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
        {
            // should null terminate if you want to treat the words as strings
            a[i][j] = '\0';

            i++;
            j = 0;
            continue;
        }
        a[i][j++] = c;
    }
}
```

This should store one word (up to 99 chars, as separated by space or newline char) in each of the 1000 arrays of 100 chars that `a` now holds.

You should of course add checks to make sure the 99 char limit per word and 1000 word limit is never exceeded.

Comment: I didn't want to use two dimensional array concept but rather array arithmetic to gain more proficiency on that concept.